# Need to extract column names from string in c#

Tags: c#, regex

I am trying to extract all column names from an SQL calculation string.
The data is held in a cell in a datatable and is determined by the square brackets surrounding the column. 
I can extract each instance of [*], but have just noticed that i have an issue. Some of the columns have table names and some have schema and table names.
E.g. [column] [table].column] or [schema].[table].[column]
How do i amend this code to pull everything between the first "[" and the last "]" that is not followed by a period?

The following code populates datatable1, then reads through to find any "column_calculation_formula" cell that contains a column name ([*]) and adds it to a duplicate of the row into a new datatable ready for upload.
I tried appending the new row to the datatable, but this caused issues.

```
DataTable WBC_DTable = PopulateDataTable();
DataTable WBC_DTable2 = new DTSetup.WBDataTablesSetup().WBDSColumnsSetup();
Regex regex = new Regex(@"\[(.*?)\]");

long Rows = WBC_DTable.Rows.Count;
foreach (DataRow row in WBC_DTable.Rows)
{
    string InputString = row["column_calculation_formula"].ToString();
    MatchCollection matches = regex.Matches(InputString);
    List<string> Output = new List<string>();
    foreach (Match m in matches)
    {
        Output.Add(m.Value);
        TextBoxAppend("Before: " + m.Value);
    }
    List<string> distinct = Output.Distinct().ToList();
    foreach (string value in distinct)
    {
        TextBoxAppend("After: " + value);

        if (distinct.Count() > 0)
        {
            DataRow NewRow = WBC_DTable2.NewRow();
            NewRow.ItemArray = row.ItemArray;
            NewRow["column_datatype"] = "SubColumn";
            NewRow["column_name"] = value;
            WBC_DTable2.Rows.Add(NewRow);
        }
    }
    DataRow NewRow2 = WBC_DTable2.NewRow();
    NewRow2.ItemArray = row.ItemArray;
    WBC_DTable2.Rows.Add(NewRow2);
}
```

Fairly confident that this should just be an alteration of the Regex call, but i dont know enough about Regex to be able to do this.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Are you trying to extract strings like `[abc_1].[def_2]`? `var res = Regex.Matches(s, @"\[\w+](?:\.\[\w+])*").Cast<Match>().Select(x => x.Value).ToList()`?

Comment: The calculation can contain a mixture of all 3. but they will always be surrounded by brackets. So what i need to do is collect from the opening bracket, to the next available closing bracket where the closing bracket is not followed by a full stop. This would capture all iterations of the the columns in the calculation.

Comment: Ok, try `\[.*?](?!\.)` then with my above code.

Comment: Added your regex to my code and, well if you were here i would kiss you. :)
Post your last comment as the answer and i will accept it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may use

```
var res = Regex.Matches(s, @"\[.*?](?!\.)")
    .Cast<Match>().
    Select(x => x.Value)
    .ToList()
```

[**See the online pattern demo**](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%5c%5b.*%3f%5d%28%3f!%5c.%29&i=%5bcolumn%5d+%5btable%5d.column%5d+or+%5bschema%5d.%5btable%5d.%5bcolumn%5d+).

**Details**

- `\[` - a literal `[`

  - `.*?` - any 0+ chars other than a newline, as few as possible
- `](?!\.)` - a `]` char not immediately followed with a `.`.

Comment: Thank you Wiktor! you are a life saver!

Comment: I have a related issue, how do i edit the regex to ignore [ and ] if they are surrounded by quotes?
Example: REPLACE(REPLACE([field_name],"[",""),"]","") should only return [field_name], but currently returns [field_name] and [",""),"].

Comment: never mind, took a shot with your code and your description and came up with this: (?!\")\[(?!\").*?(?!\")](?!\.)(?!\") Tested it on the link you provided also, works! even without answering you helped me. Thanks Wiktor.

Comment: @DDuffy I suggest using a well-known trick: match what you do not need and capture what you need: `Regex.Matches(s, @"""[^""]*""|(\[.*?])(?!\.)").Cast<Match>().Select(x => x.Groups[1].Value)` (see [this regex demo](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%22%5b%5e%22%5d*%22%7c%28%5c%5b.*%3f%5d%29%28%3f!%5c.%29&i=%5bcolumn%5d+%5btable%5d.column%5d+or+%5bschema%5d.%5btable%5d.%5bcolumn%5d+%0d%0aREPLACE%28REPLACE%28%5bfield_name%5d%2c%22%5b%22%2c%22%22%29%2c%22%5d%22%2c%22%22%29)).