# Java regex in String replaceAll: negative look ahead does not work as expected

Tags: java, regex, string, string-matching

I am trying to process text and replace all the occurence that start with "www." with a certain word (in this cases "Banana"), but I want to exclude all the cases in which there is "http://" before the "www".

When I use a positive lookahead it works (only the http://www case changes), but when I use a negative lookahead - both words change.

Can you help me with this one?

```
String baseString = "replace this: www.q.com and not this:http://www.q.com";
String positiveLookahead = baseString.replaceAll("(?:http://)www([^ \n\t]*)", "Banana");
String negativeLookahead = baseString.replaceAll("(?!http://)www([^ \n\t]*)", "Banana");

//positiveLookahead works (changes only the scond phrase), but positiveLookahead does not (changes both)
```

Comment: Shouldn't you be looking behind, not ahead?

Comment: @khelwood You are right, see Wiktor response. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a negative [lookbehind](https://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html#lookbehind), `(?<!http://)`:

```
String negativeLookahead = baseString.replaceAll("(?<!http://)www[^ \n\t]*", "Banana");
```

The `(?<!http://)www[^ \n\t]*` pattern matches:

- `(?<!http://)` - a location in the string that is not immediately preceded with `http://`
- `www` - a literal `www` substring
- `[^ \n\t]*` - any 0+ chars other than space, newline and carriage return (probably you want to try `\\S*` instead).

Comment: Thanks, that's working :) So what does lookahead do?

Comment: @TalSheffer A negative lookahead matches a location in the string that is not immediately *followed* with a pattern, so `(?!a)b` is always equal to `b` as `b` is not an `a`.

Comment: Got it. So what would be a legit use for a negative lookahead?

Comment: @TalSheffer Plenty. For example, see [this today's answer of mine](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51982341/3832970). More on [negative lookahead here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31201690/find-word-not-followed-by/31201710#31201710), and [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32886477/regexp-find-numbers-in-a-string-in-any-order/32886855#32886855).

Comment: Thank you very much! Much appriciated!